# Laravel - query to select with "with" and "where" clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, backend, back

I have the following:

```
public function filterStudentsByDateOfInterview($interview_date)
{
    //return students with the day of interview:

     $students = Students::with('interviews')
         ->where('interviews.interview_date', $interview_date) //this returns me an error
         ->get();

    return $students;
}
```

my question  is the following:
how can I make the `where` statement on the interviews column? if I don't pass the where statement, works. But I need to get only the data where the date is equal to my param of the function.

The error it returns me:

```
Unknown column 'interviews.interview_date' in 'where clause'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass callaback function like that

```
public function filterStudentsByDateOfInterview($interview_date)
{
    //return students with the day of interview:

     $students = Students::whereHas('interviews' ,function($query) use($interview_date){
        $query->where('interview_date', $interview_date);
     })->get();
         

    return $students;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the error still the same